# I cannot import what I need to, to use MaterialContainerScheme

Tags: ios, swift, material-components

I wanted to switch over to using the beta podspec, and updating my Podfile according to the documentation, and received the error "unable to find a specification for MaterialComponentsbeta`.

### Reproduction steps

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Updated `Podfile` with `pod  'MaterialComponentsBeta', :git => 'https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios', :branch => 'develop'`
2. Ran `pod install`.
3. Received error.

### Expected behavior

Install appropriate pod libraries

### Actual behavior

Received the following error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `AlertOnboarding` from `https://github.com/doronkatz/AlertOnboarding.git`, branch `master`
Pre-downloading: `MaterialComponentsBeta` from `https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios`, branch `develop`
[!] Unable to find a specification for 'MaterialComponentsBeta'.

[!] Unable to load a podspec from `MaterialComponentsSnapshotTests.podspec`, skipping:

Pod::DSLError

[!] Unable to load a podspec from `MaterialComponents.podspec`, skipping:

Pod::DSLError

[!] Unable to load a podspec from `MaterialComponentsBeta.podspec`, skipping:

Pod::DSLError
```

### Platform (please complete the following information)

- Cocoapod 1.2.0.rc.1
- Mojave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using wrong url, you should try following to fix your issue.

```
pod 'MaterialComponentsBeta', :git => 'https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios.git'
```

See this documentation [Material Design Beta Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/stable/contributing/beta_components.md)

Comment: No. I tried without branch still didn’t work. Have you tried on your end ?

Comment: With and without .git postfix

Comment: @Doz, I have tried without brach and it's worked for me.

Comment: I'm using Cocoapod version `1.7.0.beta.2` and MacOS Mojave.

Comment: Never mind. I actually uninstalled and re-installed cocoapods and it works. Im at 1.6.1 version and it works okay. So thanks. I guess it was just my cocoapods version was messed up.